# Row level security using SQLDeveloper tool --ORACLE

Tags: database, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am unable to see the RLS policies applied on sechema/table using SQL Developer. Earliar I have been using TOAD, in which I can see the RLS policy under Script tab.
Can anyone suggest to to see/edit and implement Row level security using SQL developer.

Comment: Most probably this is not implemented in SQL Developer. You should file an enhancement request: http://sqldeveloper.oracle.com/

Answer (score 0):

After these many days also I haven't got answer. I have done my on reserch and found out that all the policies will be stored in DBA_POLICIES table.